# How are these expressions named: a = 1 and (a = 1)

Tags: r

I came across an object with round brackets like: `(a = 1)`

In contrast to `a = 1`, with `(a = 1)` the output is presented in the console.

```
a = 1   # a=1 on console
(a = 1) # a=1 and [1] 1 on console
```

My question is how do you call this situation? Object in round brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment operators (`=` and `<-`, to name two of several) both do their job (assign to a variable) and *invisibly* return the value assigned. In some cases, this allows "chaining" assignment,

```r
aa <- ab <- ac <- 5
```

but has some other uses. Some incorrectly assume that it returns the entire LHS variable, but it only (invisibly) returns the value passed through it.

```r
vec <- 1:4
(vec[2] <- 99)
# [1] 99
```

It is sometimes used in answers (here on SO and elsewhere) as a short-hand for both *assigning* something and *showing* what that is. For instance, see the difference *in presentation only* between the following two commands:

```r
dat <- data.frame(a=1, b=2)
### (nothing printed)

(dat <- data.frame(a=1, b=2))
#   a b
# 1 1 2
```

To your question *"how do you call this"*, I'm not sure there's a great answer for that. Because it is using `invisible(.)` in the return value, the console's default `print` methods are not called. By wrapping it in parens, you are subverting that intent, so it is doing the default console thing of printing a value.

A good way to describe it is *"an assignment wrapped in parentheses"*.